# Splitting single row into multiple rows using vanilla Table with reactjs

Tags: reactjs, html-table

I am having trouble in fragmenting table rows from the JSON fetched data.

Code looks like below:

```
                        <table>
                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="col">Location ID #</th>
                                <th scope="col">Device Name</th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            {Object.keys(deviceList).map((key, index) => {
                                return (
                                    <tr key={index}>
                                        {deviceList[key].ports.map(port => port.value.id)
                                            .map(ids => {
                                                console.log("type", typeof(ids)) // it says number
                                                return <td>{ids}</td>
                                                })
                                            }
                                    </tr>
                                )
                            })}
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

```
actual result:
ID.     Name. 
23301   24401
99501   87701
22201
```

The above result is because one port can have multiple ID's but it shows that in parallel instead in the next row. So there are three ports and portA has two devices, portB has two devices and portC has just one.

```
expected result:
ID.     Name. 
23301   
24401   
99501
87701
22201
```

Comment: I could fix it by changing the way I was implementing it.
 {Object.keys(deviceLookup).map(key => {
                                return deviceLookup[key].ports.map(port => {
                                    return ( <tr>
                                            <td> {port.parentSite[0].value.siteId}</td>
                                            <td>{port.parentSite[0].value.name}</td>
                                        </tr>

Answer (score 0):

I could fix it by changing the way I was implementing it.

```
 {Object.keys(deviceList).map(key => {
                                return deviceList[key].ports.map(port => {
                                    return (
                                        <tr>
                                            <td> {port.value.siteId}</td>
                                            <td>{port.value.name}</td>
                                            <td>{deviceList[key].value.targetId === undefined ? deviceList[key].value.name : deviceList[key].value.targetId}</td>
                                            <td>{deviceList[key].value._type}</td>
                                            <td>{port.description === undefined ? deviceLookup[key].value.name : deviceList[key].value.name + ' ' + "[" + port.description + "]"}</td> 
</tr>
                                        )
                                    })
                                })
                            }
```